# Problema al mostrar error en la vista

Tags: php, vue.js, post, axios

Tengo una mini aplicación en Vue y estoy realizando una petición POST con AXIOS a un archivo PHP de prueba.
Este archivo PHP me devuelve un valor o un eror básicamente.
Al devolverme un error que controlo perfectamente:

```
 checkPop2: function() {
            this.errores = [];
            if (this.usuario.nombre && this.usuario.email) {

                console.log('todo OK');
                axios.post('lib/model/model.php', { params: { mail: this.usuario.email } })
                    .then(function(response) {
                        if (response.data.message) {
                            console.log(response.data.message);
                            this.messageerror = response.data.message;
                            this.errores.push(messageerror);
                        } else {
                            console.log(response.data);
                        }
```

Lo pego en la variable "this.errores".
Que leo en la vista:

```
<p v-if="errores.length">
<p v-for="error in errores">{{ error }}</p>
</p>
```

Esto me funciona perfectamente validando otros campos, pero el problema que estoy teniendo es desde que estoy usando AXIOS, no controlo todavía esta libreria, una cosa a subrayar esque al guardar el error en this.messageerror , contiene el error en sí, no me viene vacío.
En resumen, en la llamada AXIOS me devuelve un error en el caso que estoy , y no me lo pinta en la vista.

Answer (score 1):

El valor de `this` es determinado por el contexto en el que está siendo ejecutado. Seguramente tu problema es que el contexto en el que estás usando `this` ha cambiado entre librerías y objetos.

Para resolver esto puedes crear una variable global, digamos que la llamas `customThis` y le asignas el valor de `this` que tu necesitas o puede ser un simple objeto que guarde variables.

```js
var customThis = '',
        consola = document.getElementById('consola'),
        funcion = {
            asigna: function () {
                this.error = 'Este error sirve';
                customThis = this;
            }
        };

muestraError = function () {
    consola.innerHTML = 'Valor de <b>this:</b> ' + this.error + '<br />' + 'Valor de <b>customThis:</b> ' + customThis.error;
};

funcion.asigna();
muestraError();
```

```html
<div id="consola"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias, al final opté por llamar a una función donde le pasaba el error y así lo mostraba correctamente, era tema de contexto efectivamente. Gracias